# Minecraft Command Blocks - Empty players inventory to chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to build a spleef arena (and in the future more games) on a server that for everyone except admin is survival only. I want to set something up so that when they enter the waiting area to play, a set of command blocks empty their inventory to a chest, gives them the items needed for the game, removes said items after the game, then teleports them to en exit room with the chest containing their items.

Is this possible and how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure `/gamerule keepInventory` is `false`.
2. Teleport the player above a hopper which feeds into the chest you want to store their items in:

[image: Cell above hopper feeding into chest]

(You should probably make the chest a double chest.)

3. Kill the player, and all their items will fall into the hopper and then get fed into the chest.

Comment: it might also have an array of these set up with an armorstand teleporting around to the unused ones. That way multiple players could play/drain their inventories at one time without mixing each others' stuff.

Comment: You can use the command /effect @p 7 10 15 to kill the player with command blocks (without having to teleport them to the void)

Comment: @AngusAtkinson Or just `/kill @p`.

Comment: @colorfusion I thought /kill didn't work with command blocks? They must have updated it in 1.8

Comment: @AngusAtkinson  I think it has worked in command blocks for as long as it's had a selector.

Comment: @colorfusion I remember having to revert to the void in version 1.5-1.7, I'll check for 1.8 when I get a chance

Comment: @colorfusion Turns out you were right, as of version 1.8 you can use the command `/kill @p`. I tested this on v.1.7.9 and v1.8.4

Comment: You can also give them Night Vision (ID 16) and Blindness (ID 15) so they see nothing.